# soundcloud search api ignoring duration filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soundcloud

I'm experimenting a bit with the **soundcloud** api... Cool stuff, however:

It looks like when I try to apply a filter to search for tracks, the api **ignores** the duration...

See code snipper below. The purpose is to search for (10) trance tracks in the last 2 months, ordered by popularity, that have a duration of more than an hour.... As far as I know, the duration has to be specified in milliseconds (hence the * 100)
Btw, The soundcloud object is SC, initialised with my API key

Am I doing something wrong, because then I look at the console, most tracks are **less** then an hour?

Thanks!

Sander

```
Soundcloud.get("/tracks", {
   genres: "Trance,trance",
   order: "hotness",
   limit: 10,
   created_at: {
       from: moment().subtract(2, 'months').format("YYYY-MM-DD") 
   },
   duration: {
       from: 3600 * 1000 // seconds * 1000
   }
}, function(tracks) {
   console.log('tracks', tracks);
});
```

Comment: When you remove the "duration", does that change anything with the result? Just to check if the duration is ignored or not..

Comment: Sorry for digging up corpses, but did you manage to solve this issue? I am running into similar problems, from what I have experienced it seems, that adding the genre filter causes this problem, without genre filter, at least in my case, it seems to be working as expected. See here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395473/soundcloud-api-genres-and-duration

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use `"duration[from]"` instead of your object definition. It's what I use and SoundCloud gives me consistently matching results.

Secondly, change your format in the `created_at` param to `.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")`.