# Why duration filter not working properly for soundcloud search api?

Tags: filter, soundcloud, duration

My Question is almost same of the following link :
[soundcloud search api ignoring duration filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024747/soundcloud-search-api-ignoring-duration-filter)

As that link didn't provide a good answer so i question it again .

My problem is : 
i write a code as like this

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
});

// find all tracks with the genre 'punk' that have a tempo greater than 120 bpm.
SC.get('/tracks', { genres: 'punk', duration: { from: 15000, to:18000 } }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
</script>
```

This give me some tracks which is not between duration 15000 - 18000 .

Did i do anything wrong ?

Can anybody share a sample by using duration filter ?

N.B: Same thing also occur for bpm filter .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe something got updated and you are all set.... but I just did this this way.

```
//setup
 search = {};
 search.q = "timba";
 search.limit = 20;
 search.sortBy = "created_at";
 search.duration = {};
 search.duration.fromSec = 60;
 search.duration.toSec = 480;

//search method
 search.duration.from = search.duration.fromSec*1000;
 search.duration.to = search.duration.toSec * 1000;

SC.get('/tracks', search).then(function(tracks) {
..
..
```

Have had no issues with the results